# Initialization of Net .dll's through a RegFree Com-visible wrapper fails only from one specific directory

Tags: .net-4.0, vb6, com-interop, side-by-side, regfreecom

I experienced something very curious:
We have currently a hybrid VB6/Net application. The VB6 code calls the Net code through Com-Visible Net Wrappers wich are activated through RegFree Com (manifests). This works very well, our customers can have different versions of our application that use different versions of the Net code and there never is a conflict.

Today I found to my puzzlement that a new test version of our app failed to initialize the Net dll's from the C:\Program Files\OurApp directory. This is the directory where umpteen previous test versions had resided. If I install the same app to C:\Program Files\OurApp2 the application works flawlessly.

I tried uninstalling, I tried deleting the entire C:\Program Files\OurApp folder, but anytime I reinstall the app to this specific folder the Net code does not run. So, obviously somewehere else some information about the RegFree Com pertaining to the C:\Program Files\OurApp folder is stored.

I got rid of the problem after a system restore.

What happened? How do I prevent our customers from running into this problem?

Comment: I had a similar problem to this several weeks ago.  It is worth searching the registry for obselete references to DLL files.  This resolved the problem for me.

Comment: @w0051977 thanks. If that is the case then a System Restore is the only solution.

Comment: You might be able to use a reg cleaner to clear out any invalid references. not sure if CCleaner can do this but worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

> So, obviously somewehere else some information about the RegFree Com
>   pertaining to the C:\Program Files\OurApp folder is stored.

Based on my previous experience, your diagnostic should lead you to find the registry information containing your library registration. try to run regedit.exe, use Ctrl + F to find your class, and modify / delete incorrect value.